# Difference between using KEY/CONSTRAINT instead of FOREIGN KEY?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using the Laravel framework's migrations feature to create a foreign key within a database. Using the code

```
Schema::table('posts', function($table){
    $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('category_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('categories');
});
```

produces the MySQL output (from `SHOW CREATE TABLE posts`)

```
`category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
KEY `posts_category_id_foreign` (`category_id`),
CONSTRAINT `posts_category_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`)
```

Why does Laravel use the `KEY` and `CONSTRAINT ... FOREIGN KEY ... REFERENCES ...` to make a new index instead of the more common `FOREIGN KEY ... REFERENCES ...` on the column referencing the foreign key?

Answer (score 0):

Because MySql simply ignores inline references specification, they write about this here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html

> MySQL does not recognize or support “inline REFERENCES specifications”
>   (as defined in the SQL standard) where the references are defined as
>   part of the column specification. MySQL accepts REFERENCES clauses
>   only when specified as part of a separate FOREIGN KEY specification.